# How can I use OData web service to populate SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, web-services, visual-studio-2015, bdc-model

How can I utilize a query OData web service to populate it's data in SharePoint External Lists? Previously I was using SOAP web services, where I created a web reference and BDC Model in My SharePoint project.
 After deploying the solution, I am able to create an external list in SharePoint and specify the external content type.
How can this be implemented using OData web service?

Kindly advise on how this can be achieved on SharePoint Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to following articles to create a SharePoint 2016 External Content Type through OData:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-an-external-list-using-an-odata-data-source-in-sharepoint

https://vladtalkstech.com/2016/05/creating-a-sharepoint-2016-external-content-type-trough-odata-in-vs-2015-with-ef6.html